# Jquery Datatable get all filtered data across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a very old version of DataTable Jquery lib, v 1.1.6. I am trying to get all filtered data across all pages, but it always returns the whole unfiltered data. Here is what I got:

```
var getAllFilteredData = function() {
var tableData = $('#myTable').dataTable({"bFilter": "applied"}).fnGetData();
...//do sth with the data;
}
```

I have tried the several ways I found on web but it doesn't work for me, most of them said "function not defined". I am assuming it is because my version.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable().$('tr', {"filter":"applied"}));
$("#myTable").dataTable()._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
$("#myTable").dataTable().fnFilter("some text");
```

I tried not to upgrade my version because it would break other codes.

Does anyone know how to address this issue? Please help.. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to lets say 1.9.1 ..? The methods you are refering to was not available in 1.6.x. I cannot see what other codes should fail by changing from 1.6 to 1.9 ...Just my two c.

Comment: Thank you! Good suggestion! I tried the upgrading but it didn't work out. But I found out another way. I will post it in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that solve my problem. Refer to [THIS LINK](http://web.archive.org/web/20110623214415/http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api). 
Tried this:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetFilteredNodes = function ( oSettings ) {
var anRows = [];
for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
    var nRow = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr;
    anRows.push( nRow );
}
return anRows; };
```

There is a built-in fn in the newer version of DataTable. But if you are using a old version. You can try using this. It works for me.